# Typescript - A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new of Angular2/Typescript, I'm trying to compile my project but I get this error:

**A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value**

This is the code:

```
SyncCustomer(codCli: string): Observable<any>
{ 
    this.mdService.Ordini_Sincronizza(codCli).subscribe(
    data => {          
      return Observable.of(data);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
      return Observable.of(error);
    });  
}
```

I don't realize where the problem is...

Thanks to support!

### UPDATE 001:

I edited the code in this way and now it compiles...

```
  SyncCustomer(codCli: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of(this.mdService.Ordini_Sincronizza(codCli).subscribe(
      data => {
        return data;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
      }));
  }
```

Does it have sense to return an observable of the subscribe ???

Comment: you are expecting a return type of observable . here

Comment: put return in front of this.mdSer... so it returns

Comment: I tryied but I get: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable
to type 'Observable<any>'.

Comment: put `return` in front of the first line: `return this.mdService.Ordini_Sincronizza` ...

Comment: not working ( see my resp above ), I integrate now the question with my provvisory solution

Comment: Why are you subscribing inside your function ?

Comment: I'm new to typescript/angular, what I have to do is create a a method that calls 5 webapi, process the received data and return the result once finished... That is my main goal

Comment: What it means is that, whenever you create a method/function and the return type specified is neither `void` or `any` then the method must return a value i.e. you must use the `return` keyword in the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return data`/`return error` part is only relevant for the two callbacks, your method does not return anything for your first code, and a `Subscription` for the second one.

If you want to return an Observable, you should not subscribe directly:

```
SyncCustomer(codCli: string): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.of(this.mdService.Ordini_Sincronizza(codCli);
}
```

Actually I don't think you need to subscribe here. You need to subscribe in order to get a cold Observable to start emitting, but you should subscribe where you need the data (usually inside your component) or not subscribe at all inside the component code but inside the template using the `async` pipe.